# How to invoke typescript method from javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have written a code to read an data from table(in table I have a edit button to edit the record values).
So for that I have an typescript code in ngOnInit method as below. The config is read by an table in employee.html.

```
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

config = null;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.config = {
   events: {
        click(event, context) {
                alert('name: ' + context.getData('nameCol'));
        this.doSomething(context.getData('nameCol'))
              }
           }
}

doSomething(name) { // function declaration
        console.log('Param1: ' + data);
}
}
```

On click of the edit button, click(event, context) method is getting invoked and also getting the alert on the browser with the data that I am trying to edit. But I am not able access this.doSomething() method from click method(doSomething method is not getting invoked). Any clue how to access this.doSomething() from click method.

Comment: Maybe issue with the scope of `this` try to create a variable at the beginning of NgOnInit like `const that=this;` and use it inside your click part as `that.doSomething()`

Comment: TypeScript is compiled to JavaScript by the time the browser sees it. So there is no such thing as invoking a TypeScript method from JavaScript. Your problem is that `this` inside of `click` refers to `EmployeeComponent.config.events`, not `EmployeeComponent`. @BeshambherChaukhwan has the right of it in terms of caching a reference to the `EmployeeComponent` instance as `that` (or `me` or `self` or whatever) and using that variable instead of `this`.

Comment: Thanks @BeshambherChaukhwan. It worked.

Comment: @PramodS I'll make an answer then

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the scope of `this` which refers to config.events. You need to save the reference before hand by creating a variable at the beginning of NgOnInit. Try the following:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
  const that = this;
  this.config = {
   events: {
        click(event, context) {
            alert('name: ' + context.getData('nameCol'));
            that.doSomething(context.getData('nameCol'));
        }
   }   
 }
```

Comment: @PramodS does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

use arrow function instead of function expression which has own this.

`click(prop) { this refers to click }` if you use arrow function like

`click: (prop) => { this refers to class instance }`

```
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

config = null;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.config = {
   events: {
        click: (event, context) => {
                alert('name: ' + context.getData('nameCol'));
                this.doSomething(context.getData('nameCol'))
              }
           }
}

doSomething(name) { // function declaration
        console.log('Param1: ' + data);
}
}
```